# Why is Brownie ContractContainer empty despite Deployed Contracts?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, brownie

I'm having issues with Brownie not appending the deployed contracts to the `ContractContainer` as when attempting to index the `ContractContainer` for my `SimpleStorage` contract I get the following error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I have a `deploy.py` script which deploys the contract which I can confirm executes fine and deploys the contract(which is viewable in the explorer):

```py
from brownie import accounts, SimpleStorage

def main():
  account = accounts.load("my-account")
  SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
```

And another `interact.py` script to access and interact with a given deployed `SimpleStorage` contract deployed with the above script.

```py
from brownie import SimpleStorage

def main():
  simple_storage_zero = SimpleStorage[0] # indexing error
```

Could someone please assist me? if not with the exact issue I'm having at least with another way of interacting with a given `SimpleStorage` contract by for example instantiating it using the contract's address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this fixes it but simply deleting the contents of the `./build/deployments` directory and redeploying the contract solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can change the default network to the testnet you are deploying on. If I'm not mistaken brownie will launch and connect to ganache-cli by default. You can refer to the documentation here https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network-management.html#live-networks, or refer to the picture below[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the network parameter in your brownie script call? If not, try doing so. Example...

```
brownie scripts/interact.py --network rinkeby
```

The `ContractContainer` will contain your deployments on the network that is specified in the parameter.
If this parameter is left empty, then it will use the ganache-cli network. Since local network deployments are not stored in the deployments folder, your container will be empty.